# GETDATE() in Databricks SQL - it works but is undocumented

Tags: sql, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

In SQL Databricks, I know I should use current_date() to get what is in T-SQL is GETDATE().
We're using cluster Runtime 10.5 and the getdate() function actually works, but the word isn't highlighted and when I looked in the documentation I couldn't find it.
Could it be an undocumented functionality? Because if it is, I'd rather not use it.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

current_date() will give you the date portion only (2022-10-02) etc.   current_timestamp() and getdate() both will give you the date and the timestamp. But current_timestamp is the documented way, as you mentioned.